# Deployment of publishing pages which contain Content editor web part and summary link web part

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

TIA

I want to deploy my publishing pages to production environment.My page contain content editor web part and summary link web part. when i import this pages on production site, for summary link web part i got error "list does not exist". I want to create all pages as it is on production site. I don,t have access on Production site to create and edit pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the Summary Links Web Part references the list that contains the page where the Web Part resides on. If you open the .webpart file in a text editor you’ll see ListName and ListId containing the GUID of that list.

Try to delete the list GUID using text editor as this blog suggested and then move to the Production environment:

[Importing a Summary Links Web Part: List does not exist](http://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/vandest/archive/2014/10/23/importing-a-summary-links-web-part-list-does-not-exist.aspx)

Comment: For same page deployment when i deployed page with content search web part i got error"Web part Error:Unknown server tag. Corelation Id"...". What i have to do to deploy page with content search web part.                                                  
                                                                                                                         Thank you.

Comment: For some reason SharePoint Designer changes the tags of  web parts EVERY TIME you open it. I changed below tags and content search web part works.

<spsswc:ContentBySearchWebPart>
needs to be changed back to

<WpNs1:ContentBySearchWebPart>
                                                                                                                             and the closing tags in the same way.I follow "https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110028/editing-a-page-template-in-sharepoint-designer-breaks-content-search-web-parts/110332"  this article and its worked for me.